# What is the correct way to import external CSS file to a Nuxt plugin using Tailwind with PurgeCSS?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm following the Nuxt docs to register a plugin. I have something like this:

```
import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css'

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFormWizard from 'vue-form-wizard'

Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
```

I'm importing the CSS required for this Vue component to work. If I run `npm run dev`, everything works. The problem is when I run `npm run build` and then, `npm run start`. The styles for the component are stripped out by PurgeCSS which comes with TailwindCSS 1.4 or newer. I can't find the correct what to tell PurgeCSS "do not strip down the styling for the component `vue-form-wizard` which resides in `node_modules`".

This is happening with any plugin for Nuxt that requires to import a CSS file.

Comment: You could load the CSS via the `nuxt.config.js`'s `css` property. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, not working. Still being stripped down.